# Does "google +1" allow making links with referral information?

Tags: google-plus, social-networking, google-plus-one

Facebook provides an easy way for web site visitors to share links to the liked pages. In addition to that it allows to track referrals.

Is there the similar feature for "Google +1"? I can't find this information in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) but it should be doable...

My final goal is:

1. to provide the easy way for web site visitors to leave links to the "liked" pages
2. those links should allow to identify 'link referral' (so that will be tracked, and users will be stimulated to share URLs).

Is there any way to do that with Google+?

It looks like I can do that by generating custom href field, but then each visitor will have own url and I won't be able to show high score for amount of "+1" links to particular page.

Is there any other way except of using custom href field?

Any thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. There's no way to insert user specific tracking codes into your shares created by the Google+ plugins other than using the href attribute.

However, you can use [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and [Google Analytics social interactions feature](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial) to  see the impact of the Google+ plugins on your content.

Comment: Thank you Jenny, but I don't need to perform analysis (at least right now). I would like to benefit those visitors who leaves references.